# Promise object to DataFrame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to load dataset from package ElemStatLearn in R studio.
But when I load the dataset, my Global Environment panel shows

```
library("ElemStatLearn")
data("nci")
```

[image]

However, when I execute

```
View("nci")
```

I can see the whole data but cannot export it to a dataframe.

How can I convert or export this dataset into a dataframe?

Comment: I am not getting anything like you stated The `nci` is a `matrix` object`str(nci)#
 num [1:6830, 1:64] 0.3 1.18 0.55 1.14 -0.265 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:64] "CNS" "CNS" "CNS" "RENAL" ...`

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg this worked. But I don't understand why this happened. I usually load datasets using df<-data("name of dataset"). But this didn't work for this particular dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df <- data.frame(nci)
```

Another way to go around would be

```
df <- get(data("nci"))
```

Comment: Nope. It says 1 obs. of 1 variable in my global environment.

Comment: It should be `df <- data.frame(nci)` (without quotes).

Comment: It will return `matrix` not a `data.frame` with the 2nd solution.

Comment: You can select the answer if it worked for you, thanks

Comment: @djhurio it does return data.frame > `x <- get(data("mtcars"))
> class(x)
[1] "data.frame"`

Comment: Yes @djhurio it returns matrix. But that can be converted to data frame using data.frame function

Comment: So `df <- data.frame(get(data("nci")))` would be a complete solution.

Comment: for some reason, it still returns me a data.frame

Answer (score 0):

If you had done anything with the name `nci` that required it's modification or evaluation, the R engine would have at that point pulled in the values and you would no longer have had a promise. Instead, you asked to look not at an R name but at an R literal character value. The value of "nci" is just "nci". The value of `nci` on the other hand has 6,830 entries when I try to look at it.

The `data` function can accept a character value for purposes of retrieving an externally stored object, but the `View` function expects a real (unquoted) R name. Or you could have used: `View(as.name("nci") )`